# What insect is this, large swarms?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I live in Brisbane, Australia and these creatures arrived a few weeks ago for a day or so and then they disappeared. There were thousands of them. I would love to know what they are.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That is some sort of ant. Many species of ants have this huge "nuptial" flights, particularly after rains, where winged males and females leave the nest in swarms. Males die shortly after, while females lose their wings and start a new nest in the soil. I'm not familiar with Australian species, but the fact thatyou can see a "waist" shows you that those are winged ants.